# How to set a date on invisible element

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to read data from a website using selenium for chrome in a VBA excel macro.

https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/futures

I require data about Italian futures so I open the page:

```
driver.Get "https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/futures#%7B%22snippetpicker%22%3A%22EEX%20Italian%20Power%20Futures%22%7D"

driver.Wait 1000
driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='btn bordered uo_cookie_btn_type_1']").Click
```

Next, I have to set the date, but the element is not visible:

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='mv-input-box']").Clear
driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='mv-input-box']").SendKeys ("2020-06-19")
```

this doesn't work:

```
Run-time error-12
Element is not currently interactable
```

and I don't know how to click on the icon to set the date:

```html
<div class="mv-button-base mv-button-image mv-stack-block mv-hyperlink-button mv-calendar-icon"><div>
</div><svg viewBox="0 0 22 17" class=""><path d="M16,4H14V0h2ZM13,1H9V3h4Zm4,0V3h3V15H2V3H5V1H0V17H22V1ZM8,0H6V4H8ZM8,9H4V5H8ZM7,6H5V8H7Zm6,3H9V5h4ZM12,6H10V8h2Zm6,3H14V5h4ZM17,6H15V8h2ZM4,10H8v4H4Zm1,3H7V11H5Zm8,1H9V10h4Zm-1-3H10v2h2Zm6,3H14V10h4Zm-1-3H15v2h2Z"></path></svg></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution, but the case is weird and this is not the best solution.

```
elements = driver.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@class = 'mv-input-box']");

for element in elements:
try:
  element.clear
  element.senkeys("2020-06-19")

except ElementNotInteractableException:
```

I am not expert in python, and if I have mistakes please correct them

The JAVA code for that should be :

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@class = 'mv-input-box']"));

for(WebElement ele: elements) {
    try {
         ele.clear();
         ele.sendKeys("2020-06-19");
        }
    catch(ElementNotInteractableException ignored){
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I tried but 
Try
except
is not supported in selenium chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question with the add of Post.IsDisplayed:

```
       For Each Post In driver.FindElementsByXPath("//input[@class = 'mv-input-box']")
        If Post.Value = Year(Date) & "-" & Format(Month(Date), "00") & "-" & Format(Day(Date), "00") And Post.IsDisplayed Then
            
            Post.Clear
            Post.SendKeys ("2021-25-01")
            
            Post.Click
            driver.Wait 2000
            Exit For
       End If
    Next Post
```